# ActiveRecord and Puma: could not obtain a connection from the pool

Tags: ruby, activerecord, connection-pooling, puma

We are moving from Passenger to Puma and everything is working in some Apps but for another App we get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError - could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use:
    /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:202:in `block in wait_poll'
```

It is happening after the 5th request. We connect this with the default DataBase connection `pool` size which is 5.

We can update this number but:

1. Which is the number we should put in the pool size?
2. Why this is not a problem in the Rails Apps? (This is only happening in our Sinatra-ActiveRecord App?

Comment: It depends on `threads_count` puma setting.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `puma` gem to my `Gemfile` did the trick:

```
group :production do
  gem "puma"
end
```